# Changing the quality and converting with Sharp

Tags: node.js, webpack, image-processing, compression, sharp

I want to compress and convert jpg,png into webp and avif, but I can't find this option in Sharp's documentation. I'm using webpack and I tried to add something like this below in 'plugins:', but it didn't work. Imagemin has a 'quality' option, but it seems like Sharp syntax is different. Please, help.

```
import sharp from "sharp";

module.exports = {
plugins: [
sharp({
      mozjpeg: {
        quality: 75,
      },
    }),
],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `webpack.config.js`, you'll likely need a more lengthy config setup, something like this:

```js
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
...(snipped)...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      // default minimizer is Terser for JS. Extend here vs overriding.
      "...",
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        minimizer: {
          implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.sharpMinify,
        },
        generator: [
          {
            type: "asset",
            implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.sharpGenerate,
            options: {
              encodeOptions: {
                jpeg: {
                  quality: 75,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
  },
}
```

Some helpful links:

- https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/#optimize-with-sharp
- https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#jpeg